# Spring: Automatically create a property value with year-month?

Tags: java, spring, properties, spring-4, spring-el

I have a Spring 4.3 application that reads a PostgreSQL database through JDBC. But the database url ends with the current year and month, e.g. `backup_2017-03`. This is currently adapted manually as needed.

Can this URL be created automagically with e.g. SpEL?

Here are the relevant snippets from `application-context.xml`:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>database.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
</bean>
```

And here are the properties from `database.properties`:

```
database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
database.url=jdbc:postgresql://test-db3:5432/backup_2017-03
```

Comment: As always: what have you already tried?

Comment: @Sonata: Nothing. SpEL looks *way* too complex.

Comment: Have a look https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef, it also includes some examples using Java classes (´T(java.lang.Math).random()´), that can help getting you started.

Comment: Do you mean 'month' when you say 'date'? So '03' is month?

Comment: @MortenHaraldsen: Yes. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn's out SpEL isn't *that* complex:

```
<property name="url" value="${database.url}#{T(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter).ofPattern('yyyy-MM').format(T(java.time.LocalDate).now()) }"/>
```

with

```
database.url=jdbc:postgresql://test-db3:5432/backup_
```